# Hide labels in plotly donut chart r

Tags: r, charts, plotly

I am working on a Shiny app where I am plotting a Donut chart. The slices depend on the variable selected and sometimes are too small. In such cases the labels are displayed outside the chart like in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to altogether hide all the labels (values with % sign) in the chart and only allow the hover action to show the details?

An reproducible code for a Donut Chart is as below:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# Get Manufacturer
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)

p <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(manuf) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  plot_ly(labels = ~manuf, values = ~count) %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set [`textinfo='none'`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#pie-textinfo) to get the following donut plot which has no text in the pie elements but shows info on hovering.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can control what is shown in a plotly pie chart using the `textinfo` and `hoverinfo`attributes. One solution to your problem would be setting the `textinfo = "none"` and `hoverinfo = "text"` while specifying that `text = ~manuf` as in:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# Get Manufacturer
mtcars$manuf <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " "), "[[", 1)

p <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(manuf) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  plot_ly(text = ~manuf, values = ~count, textinfo = "none", hoverinfo = "text") %>%
  add_pie(hole = 0.6) %>%
  layout(title = "Donut charts using Plotly",  showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

p
```

You can further customize the text that is shown on hover by pasting any combination of strings with `<br>` seperators, e.g.:

```
plot_ly(text = ~paste("Manuf.: ", manuf , "<br> Number: ", count) , values = ~count, textinfo = "none", hoverinfo = "text") %>%
```

[image]